# lex/yacc no member name and declaration error

Tags: c++, parsing, dictionary, yacc, lex

I'm running into an issue with this lex/yacc calculator I'm working on. I'm trying to implement STL map to handle my variables using a string as a key and a double as a value.

I originally had my variables stored as single characters in an array and everything was working fine. Now that I'm trying to implement map I've run these error messages.

Why am I getting the union error message? Also I dont recognize the other errors. (I'll sort those deprecated conversion errors later)

error messages

```
flex calc.l
yacc calc.y
g++ -o calc lex.yy.c y.tab.c

In file included from calc.l:4:
y.tab.h:7: error: 'string' does not name a type
calc.l: In function 'int yylex()':
calc.l:12: error: 'union YYSTYPE' has no member named 'index'
calc.l:12: error: expected ';' before ')' token
calc.l:16: error: 'yyerror' was not declared in this scope
y.tab.c: In function 'int yyparse()':
y.tab.c:270: error: 'yylex' was not declared in this scope
y.tab.c:308: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
calc.y:33: error: cannot convert 'double' to 'std::string*' in assignment
y.tab.c:460: error: 'yylex' was not declared in this scope
y.tab.c:494: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
```

calc.l

```
%{
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include "y.tab.h"


%}
%%
"print"                     {return print;}
"exit"                      {return exit_command;}
[0-9]+                      {yylval.num = strtod(yytext, NULL); return number;}
[_[:alpha:]][_[:alnum:]]*   {yylval.index = new std::string(yytext)); return identifier; }
[ \t]                       ;
[\n]                        {return(CR);}
[-()+*/;=]                  {return yytext[0];}
.                           {ECHO; yyerror ("unexpected character");}

%%
int yywrap (void) {return 1;}
```

calc.y

```
%{
void yyerror (char *s);
#include <stdio.h>     /* C declarations used in actions */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>

static std::map<std::string, double> vars;
%}

%union {double num; std::string *index;}         /* Yacc definitions */
%start line
%token print
%token CR
%token exit_command
%token <num> number
%token <index> identifier
%type <num> line exp term 
%type <index> assignment

%%

/* descriptions of expected inputs     corresponding actions */

line    : assignment CR         {;}
        | exit_command CR       {exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);}
        | print exp CR          {printf("Printing %f\n", $2);}
        | line assignment CR    {;}
        | line print exp CR     {printf("Printing %f\n", $3);}
        | line exit_command CR  {exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);}
        ;

assignment : identifier '=' exp  {$$ = vars[*$1] = $3; delete $1; }
            ;
exp     : term                  {$$ = $1;}
        | exp '+' term          {$$ = $1 + $3;}
        | exp '-' term          {$$ = $1 - $3;}
        | exp '*' term          {$$ = $1 * $3;}
        | exp '/' term          {$$ = $1 / $3;}
        | '(' exp ')'           {$$ = $2;}
        ;
term    : number                {$$ = $1;}
        | identifier            {$$ = vars[*$1];      delete $1; } 
        ;

%%                    

int main (void) {


    return yyparse ( );
}

void yyerror (char *s) {fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `%union` directive in yacc/bison causes the definition of a `union` type (generally called `union YYSTYPE`); if yacc/bison produces a header file (`y.tab.h`), then the definition of the semantic union (`union YYSTYPE`) will be placed into that header. Consequently, every type used in the `%union` directive must be available in any file importing `y.tab.h`, which is to say your flex file. However, that file does not `#include <string>`, so `std::string` is not available. (Please continue reading. The obvious fix won't work.)

I can't reproduce the error message `y.tab.h:7: error: 'string' does not name a type` -- in the versions of yacc and bison I tried, the error message shows up later in the file, and refers to `std::string`; since you don't show the `-d` option in you commands, I wonder if you are using a previous version of the generated header file. (On the whole, `make` will work out better than trying to remember the correct command sequence every time.) Regardless, at least some of the other errors are the result of the error in the declaration of the `union` type.

But while you'll need to `#include <string>` if you want to use `std::string` in your lexical actions, you won't be able to include `std::string` as part of the semantic union. At least, you can't do that using the standard yacc/bison template; you can do it with recent versions of `bison` using a `C++` template, but I suspect you don't have a `bison` version which is new enough.

The reason you can't use `std::string` in the semantic union is precisely that it is a union. In C++, a union type should not contain any type which has a non-trivial destructor, because member destructors are not run when the union type itself is destructed. That, in turn, is because there is no way to know which of the union members is actually valid when the union is destructed. If you knew how to figure that out, you could define an explicit constructor for the `union`, but in this case the `union` declaration is being generated automatically (without any constructor or destructor, because the parser generator is generating C code) and even if you use your own declaration (possible with recent bison versions), it is not trivial to figure out which union member is active when the value is popped from the stack. (Again, in theory bison could probably figure that out for you, but it doesn't.)

So you're stuck with "plain old data" (POD) types as semantic union members. Although `std::string` is definitely not POD, `std::string*` is. (Any pointer is a POD type, regardless how non-plain the object it points to.) So you could make the `index` member a `std::string*`, and then explicitly manage creation and destruction using `new` and `delete`. That wouldn't be much different from the pure C solution using `strdup` and `free`. But you'll have to do one of the two.

Unfortunately, managing the lifetime of semantic values can be non-trivial because it is always tempting to share memory by shallow-copying instead of deep-copying. However, in simple grammars like yours, it is not that difficult to avoid ever having more than one active instance of a semantic value. (`unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` are not POD types either, so you can't use the C++-compiler to enforce the uniqueness of the pointer, or to automatically reference count it. Sorry.) If you never have two active copies of the same value, you can use a very simple heuristic which will work as long as you are rigidly disciplined:

In every action, for each semantic value `$n` which needs explicit destruction:

1. If the value is being incorporated into some semantic type structure, that's fine because the parser will pop the stack at the end of the action, so the fact that the value is both on the stack and stored into some other structure is very temporary.
2. If the value is not incorporated into any more persistent storage, then destruct the value in the action. Again, the value is about to be popped off the stack, so the dangling pointer will be very short-lived.
3. Use a bison `%destructor` directive for the cases where `bison` automatically pops the stack without running an action. (Mostly error recovery.)

Comment: So I started compiling using flex and bison. I realized I was compiling with g++ using the lex.yy.c and y.tab.c instead of calc.yy.c and calc.tab.c.

I'm now just getting these errors. http://i.imgur.com/7yj2DDc.png